# "JsonWebToken Expired" and "Malformed" on different machines causing Infinite Loop (MongoDB)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, jwt

My MongoDB/React project all of a sudden stopped working on localhost and immediately falls into an infinite refresh loop on localhost start-up. This started immediately after I deleted a required "name" field that I no longer wanted in the user model/controller.
Funny enough, the live link in Heroku still works. I have lost weeks on this issue.

What I have tried:

- Reset to the last working commit.
- Used a different machine without the changed code.
- Deleted and re-installing node_modules and package-lock.json files in both backend and
  frontend directories.
- Creating a whole new database and adding it to the MONGO_URI environment variable.

PC error:

```
JsonWebToken: JWT Malformed.
 at module.exports [as verify] (/home/erickbravo/ebravo/Practice/parts-house3/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:70:17)
[0]     at /home/erickbravo/ebravo/Practice/parts-house3/backend/middleware/authMiddleware.js:12:33
[0]     at asyncUtilWrap (/home/erickbravo/ebravo/Practice/parts-house3/node_modules/express-async-handler/index.js:3:20)
[0]     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/erickbravo/ebravo/Practice/parts-house3/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
[0]     at next (/home/erickbravo/ebravo/Practice/parts-house3/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
[0]     at Route.dispatch (/home/erickbravo/ebravo/Practice/parts-house3/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:114:3)
[0]     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/erickbravo/ebravo/Practice/parts-house3/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
[0]     at /home/erickbravo/ebravo/Practice/parts-house3/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:15
[0]     at Function.process_params (/home/erickbravo/ebravo/Practice/parts-house3/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:346:12)
[0]     at next (/home/erickbravo/ebravo/Practice/parts-house3/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:10)
^C[0] npm run server exited with code SIGINT
```

Mac error:

```
JsonWebToken: JWT Expired
```

This is my authMiddleware.js folder:

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const asyncHandler = require("express-async-handler");
const User = require("../model/userModel");

const protect = asyncHandler(async(req, res, next) => {
    let token;

    if(req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer")) {
        try {
            token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1]

            const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET)
            req.user = await User.findById(decoded.id).select("-password")

            next()
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            res.status(401)
            throw new Error("Not authorized");
        }
    }

    if (!token) {
        res.status(401)
        throw new Error("Not authorized, no token")
    }
});

module.exports = { protect };
```

This is my User Model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Please add an email"],
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Please add a password"]
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
})


module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema)
```

Please let me know if I need to add any more information here before you decide to delete my post. That is really annoying. Thank you.

edit:
I found this error in Redux dev tools. I delete everything that has to do with "name" in both user models and auth. I don't know why I'm getting this error if I have deleted "name" from the models and controllers.

```
auth:{
   user: {
      message(pin):"name is not defined"
      stack(pin):"ReferenceError: name is not defined at 
      /home/erickbravo/ebravo/Practice/parts- 
      house3/backend/controllers/userController.js:28:5"
     }
}
```

Comment: that `JsonWebToken: JWT Malformed` error suggests `token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1]` is not doing what you expect - i.e. the issue is likely to do with code you haven't shown ... i.e. the code making the request (at a guess, you're sending a malformed token, or perhaps forgot the space after `Bearer` in the authorisation header - one check is `.startsWith("Bearer ")` to see if that condition is true (not the space which MUST be there anyway

Comment: ^^^ "not the space" should've said "NOTE the space" ... i.e. add a space to the search string :p

Comment: @JaromandaX Unfortunately, that didn't work :/. I have added an error I found in the Redux dev tools for more clues.

Comment: Keep in mind that this app was working fine for months and resetting commit to a time when the app was working was not the solution.

Comment: Is that your way of saying "I changed nothing, and it stopped working"? Then the problem is with the client (browser)